# 'No Internet' detection delay using AJAX

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios, web-applications

I have a Web App that runs in both Android and iOS by WebView. I understand it is possible to implement network detection within the App itself but I would prefer to do it using jQuery and Ajax call.

The behaviour is slightly strange and maybe not possible to rectify but interesting all the same and I'd like to find out why it's happening.

The Ajax call works and applies an overlay to the screen to block any activity whilst no internet is available. Mainly because any request whilst having no internet takes ages to load when it reconnects. It works absolutely fine when data/wifi is manually turned off but when a mobile phone loses signal there is a definite delay of about 1 min before this is detected, there is no delay when data comes back. Here is the script...

```
var refreshTime = 1000; 
window.setInterval( function() {
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: "GET",
    url: "./offline.php",
    success:
            function off() {
  document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "none";


    },
            error: function on() {
  document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block";
  }
  });
  }, refreshTime );
```

My question is what is the reason for this delay? Is it something controlled by the mobile OS to keep checking for mobile data or is it something to do with the way the script works? Currently offline.php is a blank file and the Ajax call just checks the file is accessible. Is there something I can add in there to get rid of the delay?

Comment: That's a pretty heavy load on server polling every second

Comment: Do you think that could be the issue? Would change the polling less frequent make a difference? I only set it to 1 sec to test it would work instantly and was going to change it to 10 secs once I knew it work.

Comment: Not really sure to be honest. Even 10 seconds can be a heavy load if you get traction with your app. You'll want to monitor load

Comment: Ah, I see. The only part of the App running this script is a competitor login for a sports event. I will know how many as I create the login details. Max 400 users ish.